# If $2\tan^2x - 5\sec x = 1$ has exactly $7$ distinct solutions for $x\in[0,\frac{n\pi}{2}]$, $n\in N$, then the greatest value of $n$ is?

Tags: limits, trigonometry

If $2\tan^2x - 5\sec x = 1$ has exactly $7$ distinct solutions for $x\in[0,\frac{n\pi}{2}]$, $n\in N$, then the greatest value of $n$ is?

My attempt:

Solving the above quadratic equation, we get $\cos x = \frac{1}{3}$

The general solution of the equation is given by $\cos x = 2n\pi \pm \cos^{-1}\frac{1}{3}$

For having $7$ distinct solutions, $n$ can have value = 0,1,2,3

So, from here we can conclude that $n$ is anything but greater than $6$. So, according to the options given in the questions, the greatest value of $n$ should be $13$. But the answer given is $14$. Can anyone justify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with your answer, indeed note that

$$2\tan^2x - 5\sec x = 1\iff2(1-\cos^2x)-5\cos x=\cos^2x\\\iff3\cos^2x+5\cos x-2=0$$

and

$$3t^2+5t-2=0\implies t=\frac{-5\pm\sqrt{25+24}}{6}\implies t=\frac{-5+\sqrt{47}}{6}= \frac13$$

thus we have 2 solution on the interval $[0,2\pi]$ and notably one in the interval $[0,\pi/2]$ and the other in $[3\pi/2,2\pi]$.

Therefore, since the function is periodic with period $2\pi$ we have that $n=13$.

Note that for $x\in\left[0,\frac{13\pi}{2}\right]$ the expression is not defined when $x=\frac{\pi}2+k\pi$ thus this points should be excluded by the solution.

Comment: There was a typo in the question. It should be 2 instead of 4 in the equation.

Comment: @PianoLand I have update, the result doesn,t change.

Comment: But if you put n=13 in the given condition, the condition then modifies to $x \in [0, \frac{13\pi}{2}]$. Since the brackets are closed ones, $\frac{13\pi}{2}$ gets included in our solution. But $\tan x$ and $\sec x$ are undefined at $\frac{13\pi}{2}$. So, according to the options given to me, n would be 14. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I just figured that out. So please don't get mad at me.

Comment: @PianoLand Yes good point, that makes sense and could explain the answer. Anyway the expression is not defined also for other point in the interval thus I still have some doubts about it.

Answer (score 1):

By replacing $\tan^2 x=\sec^2x-1$ we have$$4\sec^2x-5\sec x=5$$which yields to $$\sec x=\dfrac{5\pm\sqrt{25+80}}{8}=\dfrac{5\pm\sqrt{105}}{8}$$where only $\sec x=\dfrac{5+\sqrt{105}}{8}$ is acceptable. Also the equation $\sec x=p>1$ has exactly two roots in $[0,2\pi)$ so for having 7 distinct roots we must be in the interval $[0,3\times 2\pi+\pi=14\dfrac{\pi}{2})$ which yields to $n<14$ or $n=13$. An illusion is as following
[image]

Comment: There was a typo in the question. It should be 2 instead of 4 in the equation.

Answer (score 0):

simplifying the given equation we get
$$-5\cos(x)^2-5\cos(x)+4=0$$
with $$\cos(x)=t$$ we get the quadratic equation
$$-5t^2-5t+4=0$$
solving this we get
$$t_{1,2}=-\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{\sqrt{105}}{10}$$
can you finish?

Comment: the equation in cos x seems uncorrect

Comment: yes this is right, just corrected

Comment: There was a typo in the question. It should be 2 instead of 4 in the equation.